# Elasticsearch SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch

I'm using the Tire gem in Ruby on Rails to use Elasticsearch for searching. On my local machine it works great.

On my staging server I (randomly?) get this error:
`SocketError (getaddrinfo: Name or service not known)`

Sometimes it works great and is very fast, and sometimes it just throws that error.

Elasticsearch is running on the same server and the url it uses is:
`http://localhost:9200`

I have this in my hosts file:

```
127.0.0.1   staging-server.mydomain.com staging-server
```

Where subdomain and domain are set correctly.

What could be the cause of the errors and why does it only happen sometimes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
```

to my hosts file...